# I'm getting many "spaces" in my loaded xml data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm loading xml data to my Xcode project in objective-c and I'm getting many "spaces" in my data.

For example - I load this value:

> "lehavim"

and I'm getting it in my project like this:

```
"         lehavim"
```

Can you please help me with this one?
I have checked my code many times and can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to post the code where you're loading and parsing your xml.

Comment: why not use TBXML for xml parsing?? why still old fashioned NSXML?

Comment: Use should use NSRegularExpression to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,

```
NSString *data=@"           lehavim";   
NSString *Trimmed_String=[data stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];  
NSLog(@"%@",Trimmed_String);
```

**OUTPUT :**
   "lehavim"

Answer (score 0):

As I remember I got same problem with my project when I use NSXMLParser for parsing XML. Finally, I just trim those leading spaces like in this example.

[Pesky new lines and whitespace in XML reader class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119748/pesky-new-lines-and-whitespace-in-xml-reader-class)