# Simple NSData's category to parse XML with cyrillic

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsdata

I have to parse NSData with XML string, does somebody know simple category to do it? I have such for JSON, but I forced to use XML. I tried to use XMLReader, it's interface looks clean, but I found some issues:

1. Mysterious new line characters and spaces everywhere:

   ```
   "comment_count" = {text = "\n              \n              21";};
   ```
2. My cyrillic symbols looks so:

   ```
   "description_text" = {text = "\n              \U041f\U0438\U043a\U0430\U0431\U0443\U0448};
   ```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<news>
    <xml_count>43</xml_count>
    <hot_count>449</hot_count>
    <item type="text">
        <id>1469845</id>
        <rating>147</rating>
        <pluses>171</pluses>
        <minuses>24</minuses>
        <title>
            <![CDATA[Обновление огромного архива Пикабу!]]>
        </title>
        <comment_count>26</comment_count>
        <comment_link>http://pikabu.ru/story/obnovlenie_ogromnogo_arkhiva_pikabu_1469845</comment_link>
        <author>icq677555</author>
        <description_text>
            <![CDATA[Пикабушники, я обновил свой огромный архив текстовых постов из горячего!]]>
        </description_text>
    </item>
</news>
```

Comment: What are your data samples supposed to be? They are neither JSON nor XML.

Comment: @Codo I have just posted example. It's XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized whats' going on. Your data samples are obviously `NSDictionary` instances printed in the debugger. So the issues you found are:

1. As XML was originally designed as an annotated text format, the whitespace (spaces, newlines) handling doesn't perfectly fit for data only usage. You can either trim all resulting strings (`[stringVar stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]`), adapt XMLReader to do it or use the XML parser at http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/09/11/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/ (which does it by default).
2. The funny output you get for Cyrillic characters is the proper escaping for non-ASCII characters in the debugger output (which uses the old-style property list format). It's an artifact of the debugger output. Your variables contain the proper characters.

BTW: While JSON contains implicit type information (strings are always quoted, numbers are never quoted etc.), XML without a schema file does not. So all the parsed simple values will be strings even if they originally were numbers.

**Update**:

The XML parser you're using still contains the old whitespace handling code described in [Pesky new lines and whitespace in XML reader class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119748/pesky-new-lines-and-whitespace-in-xml-reader-class) (though the comment tells otherwise). Apply the fix mentioned at the bottom of the answer, namely change the line:

```
[dictInProgress setObject:textInProgress forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];
```

to:

```
[dictInProgress setObject:[textInProgress stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];
```

Comment: Hah, I used this class. So 1: as you can see whitespace are still there, 2: it's not only in the debugger.

Comment: Where do you get invalid Cyrillic characters (except in the debugger)? And please show the code how you call the XML reader.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried to set text in UITextView from NSDictionary (with - (NSString)description method), but when I got NSString from NSDictionary before set it to UITextView it looks good. But there is still trouble with whitespaces.